# CSS in spring security

Tags: java, css, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I should add CSS to two pages to which it is accessed after a login for which data are checked with spring security

How do I add CSS to these two pages protected with spring security?

**task.jsp**

```
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value=" resources/css/bootstrap.responsive.css" />" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value=" resources/css/bootstrap.css" />" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value=" resources/css/fontello-ie7.css" />" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value=" resources/css/fontello.css" />" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value=" resources/css/prettyPhoto.css" />" type="text/css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value=" resources/css/style.css" />" type="text/css">
```

**DispatcherServlet.xml**

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

**spring-security.xml**

Comment: Does css pages are also secured ? If they dont want to be secured then you remove security for your css files in spring-security.xml.        <security:http pattern="/css/bootstrap.css" security="none"/> ...Then css files will be avaiable for all pages in your app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not mention whether you are using Spring Boot and most probably you already resolved this - but I am posting it hoping it could help someone else who:

- uses Spring Boot;
- added Spring Security as a dependency, and
- can not have CSS working (or using other static resource).

I had similar problem and here is what I found:

As you know, Spring Security blocks resources except those which should be granted access (as stated in config classes or xml). As I know it was done approximately as follows in config files:

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
  web.ignoring().antMatchers(“/css/**”,”/fonts/**”,”/libs/**”);
}
```

However, before adding above please also consider this:

If you implement Spring Security as per tutorial in

https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/

you are told to add following annotations to the config class:

@Configuration

@EnableWebSecurity

But according to this source (also Spring's own site) :

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-security.html

second annotation above "... will switch off the default webapp security settings in Spring Boot ...".

According to this source (link provided below) webapp security settings of Spring Boot projects by default contain code similar to one provided above (code which lets css or similar resources in) .

http://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-spring-security-thymeleaf-example/

(see comments in SpringSecurityConfig.java in source code).

So I commented out @EnableWebSecurity and all other Spring Security features work as expected while css is granted access.

Hope it helps.