# css file not working with springboot project

Tags: java, html, css, spring-boot, angular-ui-bootstrap

i am working on a spring boot project and somehow my custom css file is not working.the css file looks something like this, just for testing:
style.css :
`.spacer{margin-top: 30px;}`

and the html file looks like this:
index.html

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dist/css/bootstrap.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
</head>
<body ng-app="Cat" ng-controller="Controller">
<div class="container spacer">
<form>
    <label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="key">   
    </label>
</form>
</div>
....
```

the bootstrap.css works fine, but style.css isn't. The first thing i tried is to check whether the style.css is empty or not when running the application, when i did that i realized that the file is indeed empty so i went and changed the source like this :

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/css/style.css"/>`

now the file isn't empty anymore but it still not working.

Comment: Where did you create the `css` folder? Is it under `resources`?

Comment: @javaguy tha path of the css file is like this : resources/static/css/style.css

Comment: If you added Spring Security jars to dependencies then please consider this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46874103/6332774

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check whether the `style.css` is getting loaded in the browser(Check network tab in developer tools) and  the `<div>`'s margin is not overridden by other style definitions that you use?

Comment: Hey I'm not the original poster but I have the same problem. It says my main.css result is '500' (in red)  and it also says content type is application/json. Is this a clue to why my css isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

i don't know how but i finally got it worked by changing the source like this :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention whether you are using Spring Security.

And most probably you already resolved this - but I am posting it hoping it could help someone else who added Spring Security as a dependency, and
can not have CSS working (or using other static resource).

I had similar problem and here is what I found:

As you know, Spring Security blocks resources except those which should be granted access (as stated in config classes or xml). As I know it was done approximately as follows in config files:

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
  web.ignoring().antMatchers(“/css/**”,”/fonts/**”,”/libs/**”);
}
```

However, before adding above please also consider this:

If you implement Spring Security as per tutorial in

https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/

you are told to add following annotations to the config class:

@Configuration

@EnableWebSecurity

But according to this source (also Spring's own site) :

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-security.html

second annotation above "... will switch off the default webapp security settings in Spring Boot ...".

According to this source (link provided below) webapp security settings of Spring Boot projects by default contain code similar to one provided above (code which lets css or similar resources in) .

http://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-spring-security-thymeleaf-example/

(see comments in SpringSecurityConfig.java in source code).

So I commented out @EnableWebSecurity and all other Spring Security features work as expected while css is granted access.

Hope it helps.